# Ordered integer partition

Tags: integer-partitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving an equality involving compositions of an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191165/proving-an-equality-involving-compositions-of-an-integer)

> A sequence of natural numbers $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k \rangle$ is an ordered partition of $n$ if $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=n$. Prove that for $n\ge 4$, the number of occurrences of $3$ in all ordered partitions of $n$ is $n \cdot 2^{n-5}$.

I don't know how to approach. Usually I meet problems on partitions where generating functions are useful, but here I think only combinatorial interpretation can help.

Comment: I edited your question to hopefully clarify the meaning.  Please check to make sure that I correctly interpreted what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing. It is exactly what I was trying to ask.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're not including zero in the natural numbers. Am I right?

Comment: that's right, only positive integers

Comment: There are two good answers at the duplicate that I just cited.